# Wordpress Modification To A Five-Star Rating Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, wordpress

I have added custom javascript code to the header.php file of my wordpress site. I have tested this code on a basic html file and it works fine, but I cannot seem to make the vote recording function work on a wordpress post. The other components of the script are working fine (hover, vote display from a .txt file), but I cannot get the function to record the vote working. All files have read/write access.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could assist me or point me in the right direction to solve this.

Here is the part of the script that records the vote, I am fairly new to php and was wondering if there is something I can add/replace to modify so the code so it will work properly on Wordpress.

```
 $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            'http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/ratings.php',
            clicked_data,
            function(INFO) {
                widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        ); 
    });



});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);

    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}
```

[Here is a visual example for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSXOv.png)

Thank you for taking time to look at this, if there is any additional information that I can provide please let me know.

Here is the ratings.php that was mentioned in the script that was placed in the header.php.

ratings.php:

```
<?php


$rating = new ratings($_POST['widget_id']);


isset($_POST['fetch']) ? $rating->get_ratings() : $rating->vote();






class ratings {

var $data_file = 'http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/ratings.data.txt';
private $widget_id;
private $data = array();


function __construct($wid) {

$this->widget_id = $wid;

$all = file_get_contents($this->data_file);

if($all) {
    $this->data = unserialize($all);
}
}
    public function get_ratings() {
if($this->data[$this->widget_id]) {
    echo json_encode($this->data[$this->widget_id]);
}
else {
    $data['widget_id'] = $this->widget_id;
    $data['number_votes'] = 0;
    $data['total_points'] = 0;
    $data['dec_avg'] = 0;
    $data['whole_avg'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($data);
} 
}
public function vote() {


preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
$vote = $match[1];

$ID = $this->widget_id;

if($this->data[$ID]) {
    $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] += 1;
    $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] += $vote;
}

else {
    $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] = 1;
    $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] = $vote;
}

$this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] = round( $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] / $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'], 1 );
$this->data[$ID]['whole_avg'] = round( $this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] );


file_put_contents($this->data_file, serialize($this->data));
$this->get_ratings();
}

}

?>
```

Here is the complete javascript code added to the header.php, the mouseover/mouseout seem to be working properly, so I think the javascript should be running.

Javascript added to header.php:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rate_widget').each(function(i) {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            widget_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post(
            'http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/ratings.php',
            out_data,
            function(INFO) {
                $(widget).data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });


    $('.ratings_stars').hover(

        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        },

        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');

            set_votes($(this).parent());
        }
    );



    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            'http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/ratings.php',
            clicked_data,
            function(INFO) {
                widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        ); 
    });



});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);

    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}


</script>
```

Comment: The ratings.php code?

Comment: @Jonasw, hi, I have just added the ratings.php. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Is the Javascript running at all? If it works fine on a standard page but not on WP, I'd suspect it's not being included properly in the page.

Comment: @miken32, thank you for your comment, I have added the complete script that was placed in the header.php for reference. The mouseout/mouseover function of this code seem to be working properly so I am unsure whether or not the script has been added properly into the header.php or if I need to alter the vote recording function.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this all I had to do was place my ratings.php file and ratings.data.txt within my wordpress theme folder and link the custom javascript to these files within my header.php file. The javascript now operates properly. This is not the proper way to do this though, ideally I should use the wp_enqueue_scripts hook in the header.php and have the custom css and js in the css/js folders. But for now this temporary fix works and I can continue experimenting.